# How can I set order counting in insert statement SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I tried to copy data from database to another database

I have this query

```
 insert into d1.dbo.Category(Id, Name, CategoryTemplateId, 
                             ParentCategoryId, PictureId, PageSize, 
                             AllowCustomersToSelectPageSize, 
                             ShowOnHomePage, IncludeInTopMenu, 
                             SubjectToAcl, LimitedToStores, Published, 
                             Deleted, DisplayOrder, 
                             CreatedOnUtc, UpdatedOnUtc)
    select 
        (ItemID + 25), ItemName, 1,
        (CategoryID + 16), '', 6,
        1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        iif(CreateDate is null, GETDATE(), CreateDate),
        iif(LastModifyDate is null, GETDATE(), LastModifyDate)
    from 
        d2.dbo.Item
```

It works fine. The question is: there is a column `DisplayOrder` if I use this syntax it will insert 1 in al the rows, but what I really need is to count 1,2,3,4,.. etc

Depends on `(CategoryID + 16)` until `(CategoryID + 16)` changed it start count from 1 again

Please help

Comment: why cant you use identity property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `row_number() over (partition by CategoryId order by (select null))` to populate an increasing value in `DisplayOrder`. (Note:  The `+ 16` is redundant in the `partition by`.)

Also, instead of this construct:

```
iif(CreateDate is null,GETDATE(),CreateDate)
```

Use the simpler, more standard syntax:

```
coalesce(CreateDate, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks  alot @Gordon I try `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (CategoryID+16) order by (select null) ) ` and it works great please edit the answer to mark as a correct answer

Comment: maybe you can use `ROW_NUMBER()%16`